# Achartengine - pie chart disappears in dialog

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a layout with a button. When I press the button, a custom dialog appears with a pie chart. For simplicity, I am using static values. I press the back button to cancel the dialog, then press the button again to show the dialog with the pie chart, but the chart is missing, all I have is a blank dialog. What can be the reason?

Btw, I have another button in that layout to show another chart. No matter which chart I show first, the other does not appear after that.

I have to reload the activity (layout) to be able to show the chart again (for one time, then it disappears again).

I am using a tabactivity if that matters.

```
btnnumpie = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnnumpie);
        btnnumpie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    dialog_num = new Dialog(Summary.this);
                    dialog_num.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_pie_numdur);
                    dialog_num.setTitle("Pie Chart");
                    dialog_num.setCancelable(true);

                    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Number of calls");
                    series.add("Incoming (" + 20  + "%)" , 20);
                    series.add("Outgoing (" + 50  + "%)" , 50);
                    series.add("Missed (" +20  + "%)" , 20);

                    int[] colors = new int [] {Color.rgb(33, 115, 6), Color.rgb(27, 82, 171), Color.rgb(206, 13, 13)};

                    DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
                    for (int color: colors){
                        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
                        r.setColor(color);
                        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
                    }   
                    renderer.setFitLegend(true);
                    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
                    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(16);

                  renderer.setShowLegend(false);

                    if (mChartView == null) {
                            LinearLayout graphpie = (LinearLayout)dialog_num.findViewById(R.id.graphpie);
                                mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(Summary.this, series, renderer);
                                graphpie.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams
                            (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

                              } else {
                                mChartView.repaint();
                              }

                    dialog_num.show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced this

```
 if (mChartView == null) {
                            LinearLayout graphpie = (LinearLayout)dialog_num.findViewById(R.id.graphpie);
                                mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(Summary.this, series, renderer);
                                graphpie.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams
                            (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

                              } else {
                                mChartView.repaint();
                              }
```

to this:

```
LinearLayout graphpie = (LinearLayout)dialog_dur.findViewById(R.id.graphpie);
                    mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(CallStatsSummary.this, series, renderer);
                    graphpie.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```